# Remover caracteres 0 a esqueda de uma string c#

Tags: c#

Me deparei com uma situação, preciso recuperar o código do usuário que vem por exemplo assim: '000063'. Mas a minha necessidade era pegar o valor apenas de '63', usar a .TrimStart seria uma boa opção?

```
this.txtARQUIVO.Text = item.ALUNOID + "_" + item.CODESTAGIO.TrimStart('0') + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Sim, é a opção correta.

Comment: @Maniero teria uma forma melhor de fazer a pergunta para estar no escopo do site? é que não entendi muito bem o porque está fora

Comment: Acho que não porque a pergunta pode ser respondida com um sim ou não. A não ser que se dÊ uma resposta errada aconteceu. Não ajuda o fato da resposta ter um positivo.

Comment: Você pode usar Regex pra isso também, mas com o trimstart é mais fácil...
`Regex RemoverZeros = new Regex(@"^0+(?=\d)");`
 Utilizaçao: `removeLeadingZeroesReg.Replace(item.CODESTAGIO, "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser o Replace . Onde tem 0000 substitui por nada

exemplo:

```
item.CODESTAGIO.Replace("0000","")

this.txtARQUIVO.Text = item.ALUNOID + "_" + item.CODESTAGIO.Replace("0000","") + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Está resposta, além de ser ineficiente não resolve os casos onde tenha uma quantidade diferente de zeros, por exemplo `000163`, portanto a resposta está errada.

Comment: é como uma gambiarra, serve apenas para este caso né! mas realmente é uma saída.